# how to use for loop make an array which contains something like a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create an array something like this

`array=["1":"1","2":"2","3":"3","4":"4","5":"5","6":"6","7":"7","8":"8"]`

It's something like a dictionary, every value needs to be a `key:value` pair,

so my problem is how to init this type of array? The following is my work, it doesn't work.

```
array=[String:String]()
for i in 0...7{
    array.append(String(i):String(i))
}
```

every line has a bug!!

plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not something like `Dictionary` it is `Dictionary`, if you want to make a dictionary you can go like this way.

```
var dictionary = [String:String]()
for i in 0...7{
     dictionary[String(i)] = String(i)
}
print(dictionary)
```

> ```
> ["0":"0","1":"1","2":"2","3":"3","4":"4","5":"5","6":"6","7":"7"]
> ```

Comment: @ZzwTOM Welcome mate :), Note that this will give you key and value from 0 to 7 if you want 1 to 8 then range should be `1...8`

Comment: Also note that since this is a dictionary, don't expect the output of printing the dictionary to be in the same order that it was added since a dictionary isn't ordered.

Comment: @ZzwTOM rmaddy is right about order the order of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nirav D's answer; I feel the following may help:

There is a method [`updateValue(_:​for​Key:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue) that updates (or adds new key-value pair if the key does not exist) the value for given key.

So your code would look like this:

```
var array = [String:String]()
for i in 0...7 {
    array.updateValue(String(i), forKey: String(i))
}
print(array)

// Output
["2": "2", "1": "1", "6": "6", "4": "4", "3": "3", "7": "7", "0": "0", "5": "5"]
```

Swift is always amazing you can define `+=` operator that make it easier. So the code will be as follows:

```
// Defining += operator
func += <K, V> (inout left: [K:V], right: [K:V]) {
    for (k, v) in right {
        left.updateValue(v, forKey: k)
    }
}

// Usage
var array = [String:String]()
for i in 0...7{
    array += [String(i):String(i)]
}
print(array)

// Output
["2": "2", "1": "1", "6": "6", "4": "4", "3": "3", "7": "7", "0": "0", "5": "5"]
```